# Laravel Queues Send Multiple notifications to the same recipient

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-queue

My application runs on `Laravel 5.5` and use `Queues` and `Supervisor` for sending `emails` and `SMS` notifications, but the problem is notifications are sent to the same recipient multiple times,

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

How many times exactly? If it's equal to `--tries` option when you spawn the workers, then your notification is sent and an error occurs after that in your code, Laravel catches the error and resend the notification according to the `--tries` option. Check the log messages, you may find an error in your codebase.

Comment: In errors log there's nothing and there's nothing wrong with my codebase and also `--tries` come into action if current job failed, I think something is wrong with supervisor when come from sleep start all over again.